# Spring data and play framework, spring not creating new transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework-2.0, spring-data

In my project I got class Category (important parts only code):

```
class Category {
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private Set<Entity> entities = new HashSet<Entity>();
  /*.rest of code not necessary.*/
}
```

And another class who is related with many to many :

```
class Entity {
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private Set<Category> categories;
  /*.rest of code not necessary.*/
}
```

I have a Categories controller from which I call method delete. Class declaration looks like this :

```
@Named
@Component
@Singleton
public class Categories extends Controller {
```

This is the method in my controller :

```
public Result delete(Long id) {
  categoriesService.delete(id);
  return ok();
}
```

I have categoryServiceImpl declared like this :

```
@Named
@Component
@Singleton
public class CategoriesServiceImpl implements CategoriesService {
```

And the **delete** method in **service** which doesn't have transaction:

```
public void delete(Long id) {
  Category category = findById(id);
  boolean inTransaction = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();

  Logger.info("Am I in transaction" + inTransaction);

  /* Exception while trying to access category.getEntities() */ 
  for(Entity entity : category.getEntities()) {
    entity.getCategories().remove(category);
    entityService.update(entity);
  }

  category.getEntities().clear();
  repo.delete(category);
}
```

I get a exception while trying to access `category.getEntities()` in service delete method :

```
LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: models.Category.entities, could not initialize proxy - no Session]
```

And I know it's because there is no transaction in this method. However when I try to **force** transaction on to my service method like this :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public void delete(Long id) {
```

Or `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` or any of the propagation enum, I still don't get transaction in this method.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix it? By any way, refactoring code, another approach or anything that comes to mind?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
public void delete(Long id) {
   Category category = findById(id);
   Hibernate.initialize(category.brands);
   boolean inTransaction = TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive();
   //Remaining Code Here

}
```

Comment: There is also a spring data Activator template:

http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-spring-data-jpa